# types of plugin architectures in c

Tags: c, architecture, plugins

One can design plugins in C using 2 techniques (AFAIK):

1. Use dlopen() all the way: The core code expects all functions in library to have a known name and prototype. It dlopen()s the library and gets all the function pointers via dlsym()
2. Keep one exposed known function which takes in a structure that is filled with implemented functions by plugin. This one function is got via dlsym() and called once in beginning.

Which technique do you think is better and why? Please mention any other ways of doing this if any.

Comment: It depends on whether you care about portability. Using `dlopen`, `dlsym` etc will limit you to a specific subset of operating systems. You might want to consider other options which are more platform-agnostic.

Comment: @Paul R: I'm curious what more platform-agnostic solutions exist that you are suggesting (beyond a wrapper around dlopen/LoadLibrary)?

Comment: @B Mitch: a plug-in architecture is just a convention - a contract between an application and the chunks of code that constitute its plug-ins - such architectures have been around since before Linux even existed.

Comment: @Paul R: I'm not disagreeing that the architecture has existed for a long time, I'm just curious what portable implementations of it exist in C.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second way, since it will be a lot easier:

- to load your plugin: it needs just a single call to `dlsym`, instead of tens
- to handle your plugin: you can pass around the structure with the function pointers. Instead that passing tens of functions or building such a structure in the framework in order to pass it around.

Remember that easier means less error-prone.